# Building a new path-like string from an existing one

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'd like to modify a source string which is looking like

```
"one.two.three"
```

and transfer it into a string with slashes to use it as a folder string which has the following structure:

```
"one\one.two\one.two.three"
```

Do you know more elegant ways to realize this, than my solution below? I'm not very satisfied with my for-loops.

```
var folder = "one.two.three";
var folderParts = folder.Split('.');
var newFolder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < folderParts.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
       if (j == 0)
       {
          newFolder.Append("\\");
       }

       newFolder.Append($"{folderParts[j]}.");
    }

    newFolder.Append(folderParts[i]);
}
```

Comment: There's *got* to be a way to do this with Aggregate, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this quite tersely with Regex

```
var newFolder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"\.", @"\$`.");
```

This matches on each period. Each time it finds a period, it inserts a backslash and then the entire input string before the match (`` $` ``). We have to add the period in again at the end.

So, steps are (< and > indicate text inserted by the substitution at that step):

1. Match on the 1st period. `one<\one>.two.three`
2. Match on the 2nd period. `one\one.two<\one.two>.three`
3. Result: `one\one.two\one.two.three`

For bonus points, use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` for cross-platform correctness.

```
var newFolder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"\.", $"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}$`.")
```

Here's another linqy way:

```
var a = "";
var newFolder = Path.Combine(folder.Split('.')
    .Select(x => a += (a == "" ? "" : ".") + x).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice! Just on Replace to get the result

Comment: That is, of course, the shortest solution but pretty hard to read if you're not a regex geek. Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: Also thank you for the hint regarding cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: @Christoph Agreed. I said it was terse, not that it was necessarily readable! To be honest, I'd write a comment against any of these solutions saying what it did. You can add a few extra lines of comments to this one explaining how it works before it gets as long as the next tersest answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can try *Linq*:

```
  string folder = "one.two.three";
  string[] parts = folder.Split('.');

  string result = Path.Combine(Enumerable
    .Range(1, parts.Length)
    .Select(i => string.Join(".", parts.Take(i)))
    .ToArray());

  Console.Write(newFolder);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 one\one.two\one.two.three
```

Comment: Perhaps use `Path.Combine` over that first `string.Join`, for cross-platform?

Comment: @canton7: Thank you! `Path.Combine` is much better in the context

Answer (score 3):

You can go forward-only in one loop like this:

```
    var folder = "one.two.three";
    var newFolder = new StringBuilder();

    int index = -1;
    while (index + 1 < folder.Length) {
        index = folder.IndexOf('.', index + 1);
        if (index < 0) {
            newFolder.Append(folder);
            break;
        }
        else {
            newFolder.Append(folder, 0, index);
            newFolder.Append(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        }
    }
```

You can [try it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vaeA9).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting the string first, I find it more elegant to start with what you have and reduce it:

```
var folder = "one.two.three";
var newFolder = string.Empty;
for (var f = folder; f.Any(); f = f.Remove(Math.Max(f.LastIndexOf('.'), 0)))
    newFolder = Path.Combine(f, newFolder);

Console.WriteLine(newFolder);
```

**Output:**

```
one\one.two\one.two.three
```